# Asymptotic behavior of an expectation including a bounded process

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

Let $X_n$ be some stochastic process and $f$ and $g$ some nonnegative functions. Suppose $g(X_n) \in (a,b)$, $0 < a < b < \infty$, for all $n$. I am now asking myself whether there exists a constant $0 < c < \infty$ such that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{
E \left( f(X_n) g(X_n) \right) } {c E (f(X_n))} = 1.$$

My thoughts on this were that \begin{align} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{
E \left( f(X_n) g(X_n) \right) } {c E (f(X_n))} \leq \frac{b}{c}, \quad \text{ and } \quad \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{
E \left( f(X_n) g(X_n) \right) } {c E (f(X_n))} \geq \frac{a}{c}. \end{align}

This seems to be not enough. Is my first claim true? And if not, what would we need to assume for it to hold?

Edit: Let us add the additional assumption that $E (f(X_n)) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why a statement so general should be true. Let $X_n$ be $\frac{1}{n}$ w.p. $1/2$, and $0$ w.p. $1/2$, and let $f$ be the absolute value function, and let $g(x)$ take the value $a$ when $x = 0$,  or when $x = \frac{1}{2k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and value $b$ otherwise. You can easily tell that you will be hitting both your upper bound and your lower bound.

I have no idea about what necessary conditions you might want to impose. If your $f$ and $g$ were continuous bounded functions, and the $E[f(X_n)]$ were bounded away from $0$ (contradicting your additional assumption, which I think makes things harder), and your $X_n$ converged in distribution to $X$, then that limit would exist.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see why it does not work in the example you gave. First, I am a bit confused by the definition of $g(x)$ (the part with $x = 1/2k$). It seems that still the expectation of $f(X_n)g(X_n)$ for large $n$, is $b/2n$. So, if we were just to choose $c = b$ we should be fine, because $E (f(X_n)) = 1/2n$. I feel like I didn't get your point. My idea was that the additional assumption would make things easier, because it possibly provides some "dominant" behavior in form of $f(X_n)$.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that $g(X_{2k}). = a$, and $g(X_{2k+1}) = a$ w.p. 1/2 and b w.p. 1/2. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I understood it now. It seems that you are correct. I will not yet mark the question answered, so that some people might still discuss the question (but soon will). Thanks

Comment: Yeah, of course. I think my answer, while correct, leaves much to be desired for the second half of your question. It seems you upvoted it though, so thanks. (By the way, there is a minor issue with my answer; the upper bound is hit if X_n is a deterministic sequence 1/n, not if they are Bernoulli.) Does not change it conceptually though.